# Concatenate excel formula with value in VBA not working

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to add a formula to a cell using vba, the catch is that I require to have a variable value within the formula. As there is no 'proper string formatting in vba I have been using the concatenation operator.

My code is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "postcode" Then
        Range("V" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula2 = "=FILTER(installationExport[[PMAC ID]:[Monitor Serial Number]],installationExport[Postcode beginning]=LEFT(" & CStr(ActiveCell.Value) & ",6))"
    End If
End Sub
```

But when the macro runs I receive the following error: "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error".

I have tried the vba using no concatenation - with a static value - and this worked.

I do not have any idea what the problem is and would appreciate some help.

Comment: The formula needs quotes around the value passed to `LEFT`.

Comment: Also use `Target` instead of `ActiveCell`, and add a check to make sure only a single cell was selected.

Comment: @TimWilliams I am slightly confused as to what the difference between ActiveCell and Target is, even after looking it up. What is the difference?

Comment: If (eg) A1:A5 is selected then Target is A1:A5, but ActiveCell would be either A1 (top-down selection) or A5 (bottom-up selection)